# why dosent the boolean value change to true inside the for loop

Tags: gcc, c++14, boolean-operations

Hi im new to c++ and i have this problem with a code can  someone explain why the boolean value of the frag is not changing inside the for loop.

is it some thing to do with the code or is it a property of the bool in c++14.the code was compiled using gnu gcc compiler.
my code is below.

```
    #include <cstdio>
    using namespace std;
    bool frag= false;

    int main() {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */
        char input[1000];
        cin>>input;
        int n;
        n=strlen(input);

        int val[5] ={1,2,3,4,5};
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            //cout<<input[i]<<endl;
            int k=input[i];
            if(k==1 || k==2 || k==3 || k==4|| k==5){
                cout<<k<<endl;
                frag= true;
                //cout<<"frag changed to 1"<<endl;
            }
        }
        //cout<<frag<<endl;
        if(frag){
            cout<<"Hello Seeker"<<endl;
        } else{
            cout<<"WTF"<<endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Try `k=='1'` (note the quotes around the number). "input" is of type char, where '1' is not equal 1.

Comment: yes it did work .thanks for the help.